# What's the fastest way to cast Vector{T} (T<:A) to Vector{A}?

Tags: julia

Suppose `A` is an abstract type, I have a function `f{T<:A}(x::Vector{A})`. So `x` could be type `Vector{A}` or `Vector{B}` where `B <: A`. In the middle of the function I would like to cast `x` to `Vector{A}` so it can be consumed by another function that requires that signature.

What's the best way to do that? At the moment I am doing `x = collect(A, x)`. Is there a way to avoid copying if possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If at all possible, I'd just change your second function definition to be parametric like `f`. Enforcing this kind of container structure in method signatures is a big performance bug that doesn't gain you any functionality… and just makes them much harder to use.

That said, the best way to do this kind of conversion where you don't care if the output aliases the input is with `convert(Vector{A}, x)`.  This will be a no-op if `x` already isa `Vector{A}`, but otherwise it'll be just like `collect`.  That's as good as it gets.

Here's why: two containers of types `Vector{A}` and `Vector{B}` cannot share the same memory if `A !== B` since it'd be possible to *corrupt the data* in the `Vector{B}` by assigning a non-`B` element to the array through the `Vector{A}`.

Comment: I had thought only bit type would be packed efficiently in an array. Or at least `immutable` with fields which are all bit type.

Comment: You're right; I wasn't quite precise enough in my language.  I just removed that part of the rationale — the un-safe-ness of the operation is a good enough reason for why this isn't supported.